# Why won't my jQueryUI dialog close?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why won't my button close the dialog?

Here is the code and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ThxjS/

```
$(function() {
    $( "<div id='dialogMy'><button>close</button>test</div>" ).dialog({

        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true

    });


          $("button").click(function(){

                 //why wont it close? 
                  //$('#dialogMy').close();
                  $('#dialogMy').destroy();

          });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.destroy` and `.close` are not the Methods of the jQuery Object .

There are the methods of jQuery UI Dialog .

So if you try to pass this to the jQuery object it won't recognize them..

You need to pass these attributes to the .dialog() widget ..

```
$('#dialogMy').dialog('destroy');
$('#dialogMy').dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 5):

You're calling destroy incorrectly, you need to call it on the dialog, like:

```
   $('#dialogMy').dialog('destroy');
```

Comment: is destroy better than close?

Comment: @Hello-World destroy will actually get rid of the dialog, where as close will simply hide it.  It's essentially comparable to .remove() and .hide().  Check out the [documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy).  So it really depends on if you plan on reusing it or not.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. `destroy` will completely remove the dialog from the DOM, while with `close` just hides it. You would want to use `close` if you are going to open the dialog again later on. See my updated answer for the API docs for each function.

Comment: Will destroy remove completely the div?

Answer (score 3):

You want `.dialog('close')`. `.destroy()` is not a valid method.

As everyone else has mentioned, you can dispose it by calling `.dialog('dispose')` but keep in mind that dialog will be gone and can't be re-referenced again later. If this is a warning pop-up or such this may be desired, but if you plan on re-using the modal, I suggesting just `dialog('close')`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function. You need to say:

```
jQuery('#dialogMy').dialog('close');
```

---

According to [the jQuery UI Dialog documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy):

> **close()**
>
> Closes the dialog.
>
> **destroy()**
>
> Removes the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.